# Understanding Stages in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am running pyspark job and I am using pycharm in my local machine , when my job is running I see below ooutput in console :

```
[Stage 1:========>                                                 (9 + 8) / 64]
```

I am interested what does (9+8)/64 means ?

Answer (score 2):

64 tasks to complete overall, 8 cores to service tasks, 8 tasks already done, next set of 8 tasks scheduled and running.

Answer (score 1):

It means 8 executors are running tasks 9-16 of the stage out of the 64 tasks of the stage.